# Django + Django-Rest framework cannot add M2M relation between objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing rest api with DRF and have the issue that when I try to add m2m relation between already existing objects in db I get error:

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Everything works fine when I try to do the same thing from console. Problem occurs when I execute method:

```
@staticmethod
def update_sockets():
    c1 = ApiCountry.objects.all()[3]
    s1 = SocketType.objects.all()[2]
    c1.socketType.add(s1)
    c1.save()
```

Models are:

```
class SocketType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(ApiCountry, blank=True, related_name='socketType')

class ApiCountry(models.Model):
    countryCode = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

Comment: Try to put the Class inside "". models.ManyToManyField("ApiCountry",...

Comment: are you update_sockets method outside the django project?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
try to add these lines at the beginning of your program

import django

django.setup()

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage